# Execute funcionts if checkbox is checked or uncheked ? Angular

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, function, checkbox

i have a table with x records, from table i want add items into array (or remove if  uncheck row) but i dont know how to execute functions according if checkbox is true or not...  but this not work

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in vm.orders" ng-click="vm.getRow(item)">
  <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.state}}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" 
             ng-true-value="vm.addToArray(item)" 
             ng-false-value="vm.removeFromArray(item)" 
  /></td>
</tr>
```

controller:

```
function addToArray(model) {
    vm.selectedItems.push(model);
}

function removeFromArray(model) {
   //my logic remove
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And change your ng-repeat as follows,

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" 
            ng-change="addorRemove(checked, item)"" 

  /></td>
```

Use array.splice

```
function addorRemove(checked,model) {
  if(checked ==false){
  vm.selectedItems.splice(model, 1);
  }
  else
  {
    vm.selectedItems.push(model);
 }
}
```

Comment: emm this works but my problem is not working the call functions in  ng-true-value and ng-false-value

Comment: @DaniloCaroAparicio use ng-change as above

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you are not able to invoke  `addToArray` and `addToArray`.
To achieve that you can use `ng-change` as demonstrated below:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.myChkModel" ng-change="vm.myClick(item)">

 $scope.vm.myClick = function($event) {
            //write logic to add or remove item based on model value
      }
```

Hope it helps.